# Flink checkpoint size grows continuously

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a Flink stateful job, where the checkpoint size grows continuously over time to the point checkpointing becomes problematic.  The state is of type - `ListStateDescriptor`.  Following is snippet of the code:

```
public class MessageMapper extends
        KeyedProcessFunction<String, Message, Message> {
    private transient ListState<Trip> trips;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        ListStateDescriptor<Trip> tripDescriptor =
                new ListStateDescriptor<>("trips", Trip.class);
        trips = getRuntimeContext().getListState(tripDescriptor);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(Message message, Context ctx,
                               Collector<Message> out) throws Exception {

        List<Trip> tripList = new ArrayList<>();
        trips.get().forEach(tripList::add);


        // Depending on the message content, one of the following actions are taken on the state:
        // - Add new entry to tripList
        // - Remove existing entry from tripList

        // Update state
        trips.update(tripList);
    }
```

}

As new messages are processed, the `trips` state should contain on average between 3-5 entries, with continuous addition and deletion of entries.  I expected the State size to remain stable.  What is puzzling me is why the checkpoint size continuous to grow over weeks / months.  The number of unique keys by which the data is partitioned does not change.

1. When a `List.update()` is performed, is the old list purged from the Store, or retained (forever, and hence contributing to increasing checkpoint size)?
2. Should I be setting a TTL config even though I don't care if the data is retained for months.

Thank you.

Comment: Th old list object will be removed if update() is called with a new list object. If you are sure that the list size is kept within a limit and the number of unique keys are not increasing, then you should check the size of the subtasks in each checkpoint and confirm if this subtask is taking up the most space. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/ops/monitoring/checkpoint_monitoring/

Comment: Each Checkpoint has a single subtask, which is taking up the whole checkpoint size.  The job has a parallelism of 1.

Comment: What state backend are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For each unique key in your stream, you'll get a separate state. So state could grow unbounded if you've got an increasing number of unique keys.

If that's the case, then setting a TTL would be one viable approach to solving the issue.

BTW, using a `ListState` in this manner is somewhat abusive :) Better but more complex would be `MapState`, with a separate `ValueState` tracking an incrementing key value. If the state backend is RocksDB, each map entry becomes a separate row in its table, so adding and removing items is more efficient.

Comment: The number of unique keys goes not grow, is less than 1000.  I have a feeling the ListState might not be getting "pruned" as I "delete" entries from the list.  I am deleting entries by creating a new small list and performing an "update()" on the ListState.